# Duplicate rows when save() using JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, javafx

Basically I'm creating a GUI using JavaFX alongside with Spring and Hibernate. The problem is mainly related to JPA

Suppose first time user inserts data in db like this (column **Monday** is **TRUE** and other columns are **FALSE**)

```
ID   EMPLOYEES  START_TIME  END_TIME  MONDAY    TUESDAY     WEDNESSDAY      THURSDAY    FRIDAY   SATURDAY  SUNDAY
 1      5          1.0        7.0     TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
 2      7          9.0        11.0    TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
```

My problem is that second time when inserting data into db, it duplicates the first two rows, which is not I want.

```
ID   EMPLOYEES  START_TIME  END_TIME  MONDAY    TUESDAY     WEDNESSDAY      THURSDAY    FRIDAY   SATURDAY  SUNDAY
1       5          1.0        7.0     TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
2       7          9.0        11.0    TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
3       5          1.0        7.0     TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
4       7          9.0        11.0    TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
5       9          13.0       18.0    TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
```

What I want is like this:

```
ID   EMPLOYEES  START_TIME  END_TIME  MONDAY    TUESDAY     WEDNESSDAY      THURSDAY    FRIDAY   SATURDAY  SUNDAY
1       5          1.0        7.0     TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
2       7          9.0        11.0    TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE         
3       9          13.0       18.0    TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
```

Or another solution can be deleting all those rows of which **Monday** column is **TRUE** and recreate it as previously, but the auto-generated IDs will be new:

```
ID   EMPLOYEES  START_TIME  END_TIME  MONDAY    TUESDAY     WEDNESSDAY      THURSDAY    FRIDAY   SATURDAY  SUNDAY
3       5          1.0        7.0     TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
4       7          9.0        11.0    TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE         
5       9          13.0       18.0    TRUE      FALSE       FALSE            FALSE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
```

This is my DAO class:

```
@Repository
public class HistogramDAO {
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;


 public void create(Histogram histogram) {
 entityManager.persist(histogram);
 }


 public void update(Histogram histogram) {
 entityManager.merge(histogram);
 }


 public Histogram getBesoinRequestById(long id) {
 return entityManager.find(Histogram.class, id);
 }

 public void delete(long id) {
 Histogram histogram = getBesoinRequestById(id);
 if (histogram != null) {
 entityManager.remove(histogram);
 }
 }

 public List<Long> getBesoinRequestByMonday() {

     Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT h.id FROM Histogram h WHERE h.monday = true AND h.tuesday = false AND h.wednessday = false AND h.thursday = false AND h.friday = false AND h.saturday = false AND h.sunday= false");

     return query.getResultList();
}

 public void updateBesoinRequestByMonday(long id) {

     Histogram histogram = getBesoinRequestById(id);
     if (histogram != null) {
         entityManager.merge(histogram);
         }
}
}
```

This is my Service class:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class HistogramService {

@Autowired
 private HistogramDAO histogramDAO;

 public void create(Histogram histogram) {
     histogramDAO.create(histogram);
 }

 public void update(Histogram histogram) {
     histogramDAO.update(histogram);
     }

 public void delete(long id) {
     histogramDAO.delete(id);
 }

 public List<Long> getBesoinRequestByMonday() {
     return histogramDAO.getBesoinRequestByMonday();
 }

 public void updateBesoinRequestByMonday(long id) {
     histogramDAO.updateBesoinRequestByMonday(id);
     }
}
```

This is how I am using it on button click (As you can see in commented code I've tried different tricks but none of them is working):

```
Iterator it = seriesContainer.iterator();
                int j = 1;
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> test = (Series<Number, Number>) it.next();
                    System.out.println(test.getData().size());
                    for(int i=0; i<test.getData().size(); i++){
                        maxArray.add(test.getData().get(i).getXValue().doubleValue());
                        }
                    double max = maxArray.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue)).getMax();

                    Histogram histogram = new Histogram(test.getData().get(0).getYValue().intValue(),
                            test.getData().get(0).getXValue().doubleValue(),max,cbMonday.isSelected(),
                            cbTuesday.isSelected(),cbWednessday.isSelected(),cbThursday.isSelected(),cbFriday.isSelected(),
                            cbSaturday.isSelected(),cbSunday.isSelected());

histogramService.create(histogram); // Here I'm using JPA to store in db

//                  List<Long> ids = histogramService.getBesoinRequestByMonday();

//                  if(ids.isEmpty()){
//                  for(long entry : ids) {
//                      if(histogramService.getBesoinRequestByMonday().contains(entry)){
//                          histogramService.updateBesoinRequestByMonday(entry);
                            //histogramService.create(histogram);
//                      }
//                  }
//                  }


//                  if(histogramService.getBesoinRequestByMonday().isEmpty()){
//                      histogramService.create(histogram);
//                  } else{
//                      histogramService.create(histogram);
//                      List<Long> ids = histogramService.getBesoinRequestByMonday();
//                      for(long entry : ids) {
//                          histogramService.updateBesoinRequestByMonday(entry);
//                          histogramService.getBesoinRequestByMonday().clear();
//                      }
//                  }

                    maxArray.clear();
                    j++;
```

**Update:** Histogram Entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Entity
@Table(name = "HISTOGRAM")
public class Histogram implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private int employees;
    private double startTime; 
    private double endTime;

    private boolean monday;
    private boolean tuesday;
    private boolean wednessday;
    private boolean thursday;
    private boolean friday;
    private boolean saturday;
    private boolean sunday;

    public Histogram() {
    }

    public Histogram(int employees, double startTime, double endTime, boolean monday, boolean tuesday,
            boolean wednessday, boolean thursday, boolean friday, boolean saturday, boolean sunday) {
        this.employees = employees;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.monday = monday;
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
        this.wednessday = wednessday;
        this.thursday = thursday;
        this.friday = friday;
        this.saturday = saturday;
        this.sunday = sunday;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //@Size(min = 2, max = 255, message = "Enter between 2 and 255 characters!")
    @Column(name = "employees")
    @NotNull
    public int getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(int employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @Column(name = "startTime")
    @NotNull
    public double getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(double startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    @Column(name = "endTime")
    @NotNull
    public double getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(double endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    @Column(name = "monday")
    @NotNull
    public boolean isMonday() {
        return monday;
    }

    public void setMonday(boolean monday) {
        this.monday = monday;
    }

    @Column(name = "tuesday")
    @NotNull
    public boolean isTuesday() {
        return tuesday;
    }

    public void setTuesday(boolean tuesday) {
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
    }

    @Column(name = "wednessday")
    @NotNull
    public boolean isWednessday() {
        return wednessday;
    }

    public void setWednessday(boolean wednessday) {
        this.wednessday = wednessday;
    }

    @Column(name = "thursday")
    @NotNull
    public boolean isThursday() {
        return thursday;
    }

    public void setThursday(boolean thursday) {
        this.thursday = thursday;
    }

    @Column(name = "friday")
    @NotNull
    public boolean isFriday() {
        return friday;
    }

    public void setFriday(boolean friday) {
        this.friday = friday;
    }

    @Column(name = "saturday")
    @NotNull
    public boolean isSaturday() {
        return saturday;
    }

    public void setSaturday(boolean saturday) {
        this.saturday = saturday;
    }

    @Column(name = "sunday")
    @NotNull
    public boolean isSunday() {
        return sunday;
    }

    public void setSunday(boolean sunday) {
        this.sunday = sunday;
    }

}
```

Please someone guide me how resolve this.

Comment: Can you use `histogramService.update(histogram);` instead of using `histogramService.create(histogram);` when storing in DB and see the results? Also can you provide your Histogram entity

Comment: unrelated to the question but can't you convert the seven columns for day of the week to a single column int from 1 to 7 as value representing those days? mind it's just a suggestion based on the fact that i would be in pain everytime i'd have to write true/false for every day

Comment: @LuayAbdulraheem I updated my question you can check now;

Comment: @Zeromus can you please elaborate more

Comment: i mean since you are using all those true and false to represent just one day  of the week you can simplify using a single column where 1 would be Monday, 2 Tuesday, etc...

Comment: @Zeromus The thing is that one day, some of the days or all of the days can be true at the same time that's why I'm using like this

Comment: Oh... my bad i supposed wrong since it was always only one true in the example

Comment: Imo the problem is the new operator in the button click. You are creating a new Histogram object with a new id (not the one in your db). That is, when you are calling persist entity manager sees a new object with a different id from your persisted (with the same values) and does the right thing. It creates a new row in your db.

Comment: @IoannisMitrolios can you please suggest me how can I resolve this

Comment: That is a real good question. Imo again, there are 2 ways to solve it. 1) (quick and dirty) if you are doing experimental coding you can get the object    from your db with the right id instead of instantiating one. (calling em.find()) 2) Bind the object in the ui. It is the recommended way. Now I don't know if you use any framework for the ui but you should in general. There is a variety of them and they will help you get through this new Histogram( dummyObject.get fields()).

Comment: @IoannisMitrolios Another solution would be when first time user click on button program will add the row or rows with column according to user specified data. Second time when user will click on the button program will check if row or rows with column **MONDAY** is **TRUE** already present or not if it's not present add the row and if it's present first delete all those rows with **MONDAY** is **TRUE** and recreate them alongside with newly added row. What do you think about this? . I tried to implement this but it's only adding the most recent addition and not the previous.

Comment: Yep that is the quick and dirty solution. But you are looking the tree and missing the forest here. You are doing things that are not supposed to be done by you, but by hibernate.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're doing here, but presumably the big picture is that you are retrieving data from the database, displaying it, letting the user edit it (maybe adding new entities, and maybe editing existing ones) and then persisting the data back to the database. At some point, you seem to "lose" the ids associated with the data you originally retrieved from the database, which is causing the problem. It looks like you completely abandon the `Histogram` instances you retrieve from the database when you display them in the UI: you need to retain those, and their ids.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a particular existing rows, then first you have two get the rows using some functions like findById(someId).
Then call the update method on it. What you are doing is inserting into DB without checking if the row which need to be updated already exists.